# How does Dom know the color of Letty's car?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-and-furious-franchise, fast-and-furious-4

In *Fast & Furious* aka *The Fast and the Furious 4*. When Dom is out on the road piecing together Letty's accident in his mind... how does he know the color and make of the car she was driving? He obviously wasn't there.

Comment: *"He obviously wasn't there."*  He's guessing?

Comment: He's _Dom_ - of course he would know the car Letty drives!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, he wasn't there when the crash or subsequent shooting occurred.

During the scene in question, Dom was at the crash site putting the pieces together, I'm not convinced he would have cared what colour the car was. For the sake of the viewer though, rather than narrate what he thought was happening they showed a scene with Letty's car flipping over, since this was shown in a scene and "colourless" isn't possible, the car had to actually be a colour. This scene is purely for the viewer.

Comment: Well, they *could* have done it in Sepia or B&W.  It's not that "colourless isn't possible", many  dream or memory sequences are done without color in the movies, to clue the viewer into the fact that it's not currently happening.